# "to bump your head ON something" vs. "to bump your head AGAINST something"

Tags: difference, prepositions

Can anyone help me to understand the difference between "to bump your head on something" and "to bump your head against something". Is there any substantial difference or are they both used interchangeably? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more information. A useful answer may depend on why you want to know, for example, or if you can explain why the question arose. Also, please include any research you have done in your efforts to answer, what you have discovered, if anything, and any ideas you have about whether there is a difference and what you think it might be, if any. 

I vote the question be closed for these reasons, and because I think it's unlikely to be productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bump something ***against/on*** something are the same. [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/bump_1) defines it in sense #2.

> bump something (against/on something) - *to hit something, especially a part of your body, against or on something*

Kindly note that when we use *against/on*, the verb *bump* is used as a transitive verb. On the other hand, *bump into/against* uses the verb as an intransitive verb. Reference is on the same page.

Comment: They are not the same, though they can sometimes mean the same thing. *To bump one's head against the wall*, for example, can be read plainly or as an idiom in which *against* can't be used with *on*. It's common to bump against someone on the sidewalk or train, etc., but we don't use *on* to describe that.

Comment: In the **given context,** as OALD says, they are the same. Any further explanation would be *personal* I guess! :) @JimReynolds